# Sticky menu moves slightly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal sticky menu thats sticks to the top of the page when the user scrolls.
I have a very small problem but just annoying.

When the page is scrolled the whole menu moves to right right a few pixels. I want it to not move at all similar to this site http://www.welcomewebstudios.com/.

Can anyone help

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>

            </ul>

            </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var origOffsetY = menu.offsetTop;

function scroll () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
  $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
  $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
  } else {
  $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
  $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
 }  


}

document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

css

```
* {font-family:arial; padding:0;}
.menu {
font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
border-style:groove;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#333;
background-color:#000;
font-size:20px;
height:50px;
line-height:30px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.content {margin-top:10px;}
.menu-padding {padding-top:40px;}
.content p {margin-bottom:20px;}
.sticky {position:fixed; top:0;}
li{ display:inline-block; margin:0 0 0 50px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to .menu{} the following:

```
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
```

that should do it, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/zXrNX/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help but that makes it stay at the top all the time. I I wanted it under the heading and then it sticks to the top when the user scrolls but I find if I just have left:0; it does what I want with it moving to the right slightly when scrolled. Thanks